# Facing server error while sending apple push notification using Mobile First

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to implement tag based push notification in Mobile first environment. After successfully subscribing to a tag from the device, if I try to invoke push notification from server side, I am getting following error.

```
 [3/4/16 2:12:32:838 GMT-05:00] 00006752 om.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl I Failed to send message Message(Id=26; Token=9C7664417832E11FD7438B1F335DD3D246DD6FFB0ACBF3EAEA092181222EEF20; Payload={"aps":{"alert":{"body":"Hello!!!","action-loc-key":null},"sound":"default"},"payload":"{\"tag\":\"8\"}"})... trying again after delay
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
    at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:23)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:190)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:239)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:136)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:93)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:230)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.r(ab.java:270)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:259)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:568)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:759)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:93)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.h.write(h.java:34)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:86)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.i.a(i.java:11)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.i.a(i.java:116)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.i.b(i.java:95)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.a(g.java:17)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:73)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:110)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.checkServerTrusted(yc.java:101)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:19)
    ... 14 more
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: are you using production certificate for that mobilefirst server.

Comment: You may also want to review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948725/worklight-push-notification-apns-fails-with-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexceptio

Comment: @Kawinesh yeah I am using production certificate

Comment: @idan I had gone through that but that answer was not able to resolve my issue.

Comment: What is your IBM JDK version/

Comment: @Vivin I am using jdk 1.7.0_72

Comment: Which of the workarounds in the list provided by Idan , did you try? Both ? If not can you try both?

Comment: @AkashKesarwani waiting for your response