# Apple Push Notification - End user tried to act as a CA

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification

Using this certificates (apns-certificate-sandbox.p12) in Development(Windows environment) I was able to send push notification successfully to Apple devices.

The same certificate when used in Test stand alone(Linux Environment). I am seeing this issue. Does any one know why I might be getting this issue.

```
[4/7/16 10:44:52:328 EDT] 000006a2 ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection E FPWSE1083E: Failed to send APNS notification with identifier 7, device token: sdfsdfsdfsdsfsddsfsdfsdfsdfsd
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
        at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:23)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:190)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:239)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:136)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:93)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:230)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.r(ab.java:270)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:259)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:568)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:759)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:93)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.h.write(h.java:34)
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:86)
        at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
        at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
        at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
    Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.i.a(i.java:11)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.i.a(i.java:116)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.i.b(i.java:95)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.a(g.java:17)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:73)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:110)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.checkServerTrusted(yc.java:101)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:19)
        ... 14 more

    [4/7/16 10:44:52:326 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R   at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.wrapAndThrowAsRuntimeException(Utilities.java:277)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:328 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:319)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:329 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:329 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R   at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:329 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:329 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:329 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:329 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R Caused by: 
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:329 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:330 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:23)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:330 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:190)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:330 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:239)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:330 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:136)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:331 EDT] 000006af SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:93)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:331 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-7" 
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:331 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:331 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.wrapAndThrowAsRuntimeException(Utilities.java:277)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:331 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:319)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:331 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:332 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:332 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:332 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:332 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:332 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R Caused by: 
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:332 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:332 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:23)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:333 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:190)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:333 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:239)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:333 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:136)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:333 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:93)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:334 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:230)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:334 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.r(ab.java:270)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:334 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:259)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:335 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:568)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:335 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:759)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:335 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:93)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:335 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at com.ibm.jsse2.h.write(h.java:34)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:335 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:86)
    [4/7/16 10:44:52:335 EDT] 000006a2 SystemErr                                                    R   at
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948725/worklight-push-notification-apns-fails-with-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexceptio This is an issue with Java.

Comment: I can still give it a shot to see if this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after replacing cacerts from IBM Java 1.7 to 1.6 fixed the issued.