# Push notification not received on device using mobile first platform

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, mobilefirst-server

We are working on a hybrid mobile project with ibm mobile first 8 platform.
We are facing some issues for the push notification, mainly for the iOS devices.

Using telnet we can access the following servers from our mobile first server:

```
Sandbox servers:
    gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
    feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196
Production servers:
    gateway.push.apple.com:2195
    Feedback.push.apple.com:2196
    1-courier.push.apple.com 5223
```

But when we use the mobile first console to send push notification we get the following error log in the server and the notification is not delivered.

> Exception in thread "pool-11-thread-19"
>   [err] com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
>   ...

Do we need to enable the 443 port in the mobile first server?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480178/apple-push-notification-end-user-tried-to-act-as-a-ca

Comment: Would you be able to provide the full error stack ?